# How to pass a predefined variable value into the part of a predefined hard coded string in Python?

Tags: python-3.6

I have below hard coded string which i read from our configuration table in MySql.(And there are many hard coded {} in our database, I can't go to mysql to recognize all the variables and handle it manually in the script.)

```
    string_from_sql_table = '/distribution/{partner}/{process_date}/'
```

I have below predefined variables in my python script.

```
    from datetime import datetime
    string_from_sql_table = '/distribution/{partner}/{process_date}/' #to keep simple, didn't include code to read the string from mysql table. 
    partner = 'startupco'
    process_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M')
```

I got below output when I print(string_from_sql_table ):

```
    /distribution/{partner}/{process_date}/
```

How to get below expected output without changing the input string_from_sql_table or changing the input string_from_sql_table:

```
    /distribution/startupco/20191011_1317/
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```py
'/distribution/{partner}/{process_date}/'.format(
    partner = 'startupco', 
    process_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M')
)
```

Read more on the topic here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: Sorry. I re edited my question. we stored many variables {}  as string in our database. There is no way that I can go to database and get all the variable name and do "format(var1,var2). what I am asking is if there is a way Python automatically recognize those {variables}'?

Comment: I see. But they always have the same keys, as in they are always called `partner` and `process_date`?

Comment: You must know the variable names in your code, as in your example, otherwise you wouldn't be able to substitute them.

Comment: Since you are using `3.6` you could even use the all-mighty f-strings. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: we configure/tokenize many thing  in our database. There are '{table_name}','{account_name}','{user}' etc.  I tried f'xxxx{}xxx', it didn't work for this scenario.